# Last column always shows null in Datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my datagridview, I'm entering the values in each column. On button click I'm calculating these values using some formula an populating in another datagridview.

Here I have four columns in first Datagridview, but when I press button, I can get first three columns value only. When I see in watch window, the last column value shows as nothing.

If I delete fourth column and only having three columns now, the third column value shows as nothing.

How can I avoid this?

My coding

```
For iRow = 0 To LogCalcEnter.Rows.Count - 1
            If (Trim(LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(0).Value) <> "" And Trim(LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(1).Value) <> "" And Trim(LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(2).Value) <> "") Then
                Dim sw As Decimal
                sw = LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(2).Value

                RowIndex = LogCalValue.Rows.Add()
                Dim NewRow As New DataGridViewRow
                NewRow = LogCalValue.Rows(RowIndex)
                NewRow.Cells(0).Value = fA.Text * fRW.Text / ((sw ^ fM.Text)) ^ (1 / fN.Text)
                NewRow.Cells(1).Value = LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(1).Value
                NewRow.Cells(2).Value = LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(2).Value * LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(1).Value
                NewRow.Cells(3).Value = NewRow.Cells(0).Value * NewRow.Cells(1).Value
            End If
        Next iRow
```

Here LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(2).Value always return nothing.

Comment: First turn `Option Strict On` and correct the compile errors

Comment: Yes. After setting this option and i corrected all errors. Its working now. Thank you.

Comment: But still last column shows null. If i add one dummy column,it works fine.

Comment: I don´t know if it fixes your issue but this line `NewRow = LogCalValue.Rows(RowIndex)` does *not* give you a copy or new row in your grid. It sets NewRow to the same object reference as the row in LogCalValue.